# How can I get the URL (with protocol and domain) in Django (without request)?

Tags: django, url, cron

I want to send mails in a cron job. The mail should contain
a link to my application.

In cron job, I don't have a request object, and can't use request.build_absolute_uri().

AFAIK the site framework can help here. But does not give me the protocol (http vs https)?

My application is reusable and sometimes gets hosted on http and sometimes on https sites.

**Update**

I search a common django way. Creating custom settings is possible, but a solution with django standards is preferred.

Comment: How many different domains do you serve within a single Django instance?

Comment: @AlexMorozov in my current context one single Django instance servers only one domain. But the application is installed on many different servers. Some serve via http and some via https.

Comment: I use settings to serve in such a scenario, especially when I have no request object. Something like settings.HOST_ADDRESS + "{0}".format(resource_path) should do the job. It should be reusable with min config change by extending the base settings to various settings file used specific to a site (ex: --settings=settings.site1)

Comment: @rreddy settings.HOST_ADDRESS is a custom setting created by you? I guess yes, since I can't find it here https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/settings/. I ask myself: is there no common solution to my use case? I think my use case is common. But maybe I am wrong.

Comment: yes, @guettli, it is a custom setting. I don't think there is any other way to retrieve the scheme (http/https) without request object, apart from taking a different approach like declaring a custom setting like this.

Comment: Look for default django settings that are typical to https only sites, will solve for some sites at least. If you have to choose, maybe http as default is OK because usually https servers redirect http on the server and via HSTS. More complex solution would be to grab the home page template from the site code, then run curl www.example.com and see if the result is similar to the expected page.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's special standard module for this task - [Sites Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/sites/#module-django.contrib.sites).
It adds Site model, which describes specific site. This model has field `domain` for domain of the project, and a `name` - human-readable name of the site.

You associate your models with sites. Like so:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # ...
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When you need to make an url for the object you may use something like the following code:

```
   >>> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
   >>> obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=3)
   >>> obj.get_absolute_url()
   '/mymodel/objects/3/'
   >>> Site.objects.get_current().domain
   'example.com'
   >>> 'https://%s%s' % (Site.objects.get_current().domain, obj.get_absolute_url())
   'https://example.com/mymodel/objects/3/'
```

This way you can have multiple domains and content spread between them.
Even if you have only one domain I recommend use it to achieve a good standard comfortable way to keep domain settings.

Installatioin is quite easy:

1. Add `'django.contrib.sites'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.
2. Define a SITE_ID setting:

   ```
    SITE_ID = 1
   ```
3. Run migrate.

Comment: Looks nice. One part is missing: You use "https". Where is the common place to configure the http-scheme, so that a re-usable app can take this value without guessing?

Comment: There's no such place for now. I think protocol should be stored with site. There's an issue and patch in django ticket system - https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26079#no1  I hope later it will be adopted and become a standard way. Now we can to subclass Site model and extend it with required fields. As a temporary workaround one can store protocol in settings.py, because it changes very rarely.

Comment: Thank you for providing the link to the django ticket. Nice to see that this is not yet resolved issue.

Comment: sites link seems broken; here's an updated one: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/sites/

Answer (score 37):

**TL;DR**: *There's no any "standard" "Django-ish" way of doing that, but the DRY principle promoted by the framework assumes the single configuration store, so a custom setting seems to be a good way to go.*

By default Django can serve any number of domains from a single instance, and the HTTP request (more accurately, its `HTTP_HOST` header) is the only thing Django uses to determine the current host.
As your cron jobs are obviously out of the HTTP cycle, you should store your domain somewhere in settings...

```
# settings.py
DEFAULT_DOMAIN = 'https://foobar.com'
# or, depending on your configuration:
DEFAULT_DOMAIN = 'https://{}'.format(ALLOWED_HOSTS[0])
```

...with a tiny context processor to make it easier to handle templating:

```
# yourapp/context_processors.py
from django.conf import settings

def default_domain(request):
    return {'default_domain': settings.DEFAULT_DOMAIN}
```

...and then use it in your emails:

```
# yourapp/templates/email/body.html
<a href="{{ default_domain }}{% url 'target' %}">Click here</a>
```

Alternatively you can make use of the `sites` framework, but if you're serving a single domain, the settings-based solution seems much more simpler and cleaner to me.

Comment: `DEFAULT_DOMAIN` is a custom setting? I could not find it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/settings/

Comment: @guettli, right, it's a custom setting I just made up to illustrate the solution. Name it how you like and set it to whatever host you're using. By default Django doesn't know anything about the "default" domain just because there's no such a thing - you could use `https` and `http`, serve multiple domains (perhaps even with subdomains) and so on. I agree this is slightly confusing, but this is the price of the flexibility Django offers out-of-box.

Answer (score 1):

For my particular scenario, I need to send out an email to an individual triggered by a django **signal** *(When a user raises an issue and assigns it to another user - an email is raised)*.

As signals cannot access `request`, it posed an issue as I needed to access `{{ request.get_host }}` in my template.

The answers to this question didn't really appeal to me as I'd like it to work dynamically with a change to host *(Production Server Domain, Test Server Domain, Local Dev Server*). I also didn't want to create a new field and make the table dependent on it, for the sake of extracting the host from it.

**My Solution**

The hostname for my project was the name of the vm hosting the server. Therefore I could differentiate them and assign an individual `HOST_ADDR`.

**settings.py**

```py
import socket

try:
    HOSTNAME = socket.gethostname()
except:pass

if HOSTNAME == 'test':
    HOST_ADDR = 'http://test-<test-domain>'

elif HOSTNAME == 'production':
    HOST_ADDR = 'http://<production-domain>'
else:
    HOST_ADDR = 'http://localhost:8000'
```

I could then import this into the signal, and apply as content to my `render_to_string` function.

**models.py**

```py
from django.conf import settings

def email_assignee(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs["instance"]
    if kwargs["created"]:
        email_context = render_to_string('<app_name>/email.html', context={'issue':instance,'host':settings.HOST_ADDR})
        try:
            send_mail(
                'Subject','', None,
                [instance.assignee.email],
                fail_silently=False,
                html_message=email_context
            )
        except Exception as Error:
            print("Email could not be sent! For reason: {}".format(Error))

post_save.connect(email_assignee, sender=Issue)
```

Then in my template I can use it as an email link, like so:

**email.html**

```html
{% load static %}

<p>You have a new issue assigned to you from <b>{{ issue.assigned_by }}</b></p>
<a href="{{ host }}{% url 'emissions_dashboard:view_issue' issue.id %}" target="_blank">View it here</a>
```

Comment: You can access the request in a signal (which happens during a http request), if you store the request in a global variable. Just search for "django global request middleware".

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would use something like celery for cron job & will use the django provided object for now.

Answer (score 0):

I dove into this rabbit hole a little bit and came across [this Django ticket on context processors without RequestContext](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27570#comment:2).

The comment on that ticket brought up a good point.
You can define a simple custom template tag to solve the problem.
My problem was that the request context was unaccessible for the cron task (run by celery) but the domain is needed for sending links back to the site dynamically in the email. I did not want to hardcode the site in the templates and I did not want to repeat myself over and over adding the domain to context each time I set up a new emailing task.

The example below worked for my case and was simple enough to put together.

```py
# settings.py

if env_type == "DEV":
    EMAIL_PAGE_DOMAIN = 'localhost:8000'

else:
    EMAIL_PAGE_DOMAIN = f'https://{ALLOWED_HOSTS[0]}'
```

```py
# <app_name>/templatetags/extras.py

from django import template
from django.conf import settings

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def email_page_domain():
    return settings.EMAIL_PAGE_DOMAIN
```

```
{% comment %} templates/<email_template> {% endcomment %}
{% load extras %}

<a href="{% email_page_domain %}">Call to Action</a>
```

```py
# <app_name>/tasks.py

# from celery import shared_task
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

# Could @shared_task for celery worker to hook in if configured
def send_mail():
    context = {
        "name": "sample_user_firstname"
        }
    send_mail(
        subject="elo",
        message=render_to_string("game/mail/<plain_txt_template>.txt", context),
        from_email=None,
        recipient_list=["example@email.com"],
        html_message=render_to_string("game/mail/<html_email_template>.html", context),
    )
```