# How can I get the absolute url in save model method DJANGO?

Tags: django, url, model, save, absolute

i have this model and I need to get the absolute url in the save() method to perform some http requests, how can I get it ? now I'm using the local address.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Annotation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    id = self.shot.id
    #FIX THIS
    url = "http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/annotation?shot_id="+str(id)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    str_response = response.read().decode('utf-8')
    obj = json.loads(str_response)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Site Framework, take a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34989031/how-can-i-get-the-url-with-protocol-and-domain-in-django-without-request).

The answer links the documentation for Django 1.9, which is deprecated, [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/sites/) the link for the most recent version.

Comment: is there a solution that not modifies the current model ?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, you don't need to modify the current model, you only need to configure the site framework following the instructions in the linked answer (under _"Installatioin is quite easy"_) and then you can use `Site.objects.get_current().domain` to get the current domain and build your absolute url

Comment: I always get "example.com" as website